# Spring MVC - Display error message in Thymeleaf from a model attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm building a stock market based web app and I need to be able to display error messages depending on user conditions.

For example, if a user owns 50 shares and he is trying to sell 51 shares, I would like the controller to pass a model attribute to the view saying that the user does not have enough shares.

```
    @PostMapping("/banking/stock-search/buy/{symbol}")
public String buyStock(Model model, @PathVariable("symbol") String symbol,
        @ModelAttribute("security") Security security) throws IOException {

    User theUser = this.getCurrentUser();
    Security alreadyOwnSecurity = null;

    security.setStockCode(symbol);

    security.setAmount(YahooFinance.get(security.getStockCode()).getQuote().getPrice().doubleValue()
            * (double) security.getQuantity());

    List<Security> usersSecurities = securityService.findAllByUser_AccountNumber(theUser.getAccountNumber());

    if (marketOpen() == true) {
        if (theUser.getBalance() >= security.getAmount()) {
        // remaining logic here
} else {
            model.addAttribute("insufficientFunds", "You do not have enough money to buy this amount");
            return "redirect:/banking/stocks/" + symbol;
        }
```

However, when it redirects back to the stock page, the error message doesn't appear. This is my Thymeleaf code to call the model attribute:

```
        <span th:text="${insufficientFunds}"></span>
```

Comment: That won't work with a redirect as that destroys the model (well actually it does another request to a controller method to render that view with a new model. Either don't redirect, or use redirect attributes instead of the model. Or re-render the same page and add an argument of type `Errors` or `BindingResult` and add a new error message and use the regular mechanisms.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Do you have any suggestions as to how I could re-render the same page? This is for something else - I need data from YahooFinance page to update stock prices on the view every 60 seconds.

Comment: Don't redirect if you want the same page. You can make a refresh or just push the data every 60 seconds and re-render part of your screen, all of that would be using javascript.